# How to open PHP file with XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, http-status-code-404

how can I open a php file in localhost with xampp?
The folder is located at documents\foldername

I have started Apache and SQL in XAMPP.

If i type: 
http://localhost/foldername
or
http://localhost/foldername/index.php

i get 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the files inside documents folder directly. Easy way is to place your files/folder inside **C:/xampp/htdocs** folder (Assuming C: is your windows drive).

So if you put your "foldername" folder inside xampp/htdocs, after that you can browse http://localhost/foldername or http://localhost/foldername/index.php .